# Setting up Ogre3D using Vim on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, vim, installation, ogre3d

How can I set up Ogre3D in Vim editor? I'm using Windows 8 x32bit. I've downloaded Ogre's files on my laptop, including SDK, CMake, etc., but I don't know how to connect those files and get Vim to start working.

P.S. I'd like to avoid using Visual Studio C++.

Comment: I think the best middle ground for this case would be to use [QtCreator](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Setting+Up+An+Application+-+QtCreator) and activate "Vim Emulation" in its editor settings. In this way you still have IDE/project integration, but also access to VIM modal actions. Otherwise, since Vim is *not* an IDE, you'll have to learn to create your own projects with [CMake](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Building+Your+Projects+With+CMake), build from command-line, and then integrate step by step all those steps inside Vim, as the need arises.

Comment: Note that above I gave explicit links to Ogre tutorials of using QtCreator or, respectively, CMake, to generate a base application skeleton (i.e. I didn't give links to the official sites, anybody knows what/where they are)